# console saying my array is undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, local-storage

I've looked at many examples and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here:

```
 var names_Array = [];
 var names_List = new WinJS.Binding.List(names_Array);
 names_List.push({ name: "Joe Dowling", image: "image/Joe Dowling.png", ClientID: "1234" });

window.localStorage.setItem('names_Array', JSON.stringify(names_Array));

var test = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('names_Array'));
console.log(test.name);
```

I'm getting **undefined in the console**, why it is happend?

Comment: What is names_Array, post its declaration.

Comment: it seems that `names_Array` is not an array in fact?

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox See edited

Comment: @Igor Dymov  See edited

Comment: Arrays don't have a `name` property, so of course this going to return `undefined`.

Comment: @FelixKling My json does

Comment: @user2363025: It can't. Even in JSON, only objects can have named properties. You can have `{"name": "foo"}` but not `["name": "foo"]`. If you are talking about `{ name: "Joe Dowling", image: ...}`, that's not JSON, that is a JavaScript object literal. And that's not what you store and retrieve from `localStorage`.

Comment: @FelixKling even after stringifying and parsing the json? It worked in code I've done before when I wasn't using local storage

Comment: Yes, even then. `JSON.stringify` won't create invalid JSON. Have a look at what `console.log(JSON.stringify(names_Array))` produces.

Comment: Which means that you are storing an empty array. I don't know what `WinJS.Binding.List` is supposed to do, if it should add elements to `names_Array`, but obviously it doesn't. `names_Array` is empty and therefore you are storing and retrieving an empty an array.

Comment: @FelixKling Thats what I thought but when I try and store the names_List in local storage, I am getting a circular reference error :/

Comment: Serializing "complex" objects, like the one that `new WinJS.Binding.List(names_Array)` seems to create is always difficult. Even if you could encode it, it would be difficult to decode it to a proper `WinJS.Binding.List` object again. JSON encoding and decoding only works really well with plain arrays and objects.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for your help anyway. I guess I'm stuck so

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes:

1) You just initialized the `names_Array` and didn't added any elements to it.  you are storing that empty array in localStorage.

2) Since `test` is an array of objects ( if you are pushing objects into it ), you have to access one specific object through index, or loop through the array to get members.

This code should work:

```
var names_Array = [];
var names_List = new WinJS.Binding.List(names_Array);
names_List.push({ name: "Joe Dowling", image: "image/Joe Dowling.png", ClientID: "1234" });

window.localStorage.setItem('names_Array', JSON.stringify(names_List));

var test = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('names_Array'));

for( i in test ) console.log(test[i].name);
```

Comment: using console.log( test[0].name ); gives me an error  Unable to get property 'name' of undefined or null reference due to my original problem

Comment: Yep I tried that earlier and got the error: Circular reference in value argument not supported

Comment: that means you can't convert store that array into json and save in local storatge. you need to create a new array and transfer values other than functions into new array.  just do console.dir()  to know contents in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.localStorage.setItem(
    'names_Array',
    JSON.stringify(['John Doe', 'Jane Doe'])
);
console.log(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('names_Array')));
```

Prints

```
["John Doe", "Jane Doe"]
```

Maybe `test.name` is getting in the way?